# Match two equal character in word and replace with one RE

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to convert Two equal character into single one like `bannana should be banana //remove "nn" into single "n"`. ( except : "aa" all should be convert like above)

```
i/p : khuddar  >>  o/p : khudar
i/p : maanas   >>  o/p : maanas
i/p : hello   >>  o/p : helo
i/p : apple   >>  o/p : aple
```

Need regular expression to do these type of work.

Comment: What is the programming language? Some regex engines cannot do what you need.

Comment: Programing Lang : javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [capturing group and backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html).

Here's a javascript example:

```
"khuddar".replace(/([^a])\1/g, "$1")
// => "khudar"
"maanas".replace(/([^a])\1/g, "$1")
// => "maanas"
```

---

- `[^a]` - matches a character that is not `a`.
- `(...)` - matches the regular expression and save it to group 1 (2, 3, .. if there's more parentheses after it).
- `\1` - backreference for the group 1. If the matched part was `b`, `\1` also refer `b`.

Comment: It's also apply on "aa". I don't want to apply on "aa"

Comment: Explain Please `\1` For  what ?

Comment: @higunjan, I added a explanation and a link to regular expression info site explaning about backreference (`\1`).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to only match any *letters* but `a`, you can use

```
.replace(/([b-z])\1/ig, "$1")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cQ0mN1/1)

Regex explanation:

- `([b-z])` - Capture group 1 capturing any ASCII letter from `b` till `z` (and `A` to `Z` because the `/i` modifier making the pattern case-insensitive)
- `\1` - a [inline backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) that matches the text value captured with the group above (thus, the *pattern matches 2 identical ASCII letters*)

In the replacement pattern, `$1` [numbered replacement backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) is used that replaces the 2 identical ASCII letters with 1 occurrence of this letter.

```js
var re = /([b-z])\1/gi; 
var str = 'khuddar<br/>maanas<br/>hello<br/>apple<br/>F11';
var subst = '$1'; 
var result = str.replace(re, subst);
document.body.innerHTML = result;
```